# 'Consists of a lot of' or 'consists lot of'

Tags: grammaticality, idioms, prepositions

Which is correct grammar,

- Farming consists a lot of manual work.
- Farming consists of a lot of manual work.

Also, is is ok to write 'a lot of' instead of 'lot of'?

Comment: As it looks now, this seems like proofreading. Is it possible for you to pinpoint what you think is wrong? I have a hunch you mean "consists of" vs. just "consists", but if you could edit I think it would help. (Also, please ask one question per post)

Comment: No, do not omit "a" from "a lot".

Comment: @simchona I'll take care from next time not to put two questions in one post. I'll edit the question to make it less confusing but I was not concerned with 'consists of'.

Comment: *Consists* takes *of*; *Comprises* doesn't take *of*. Personally I'd probably use "involves" here: "Farming involves a lot of manual work."

Comment: In its current form, the question is not a good fit for this site. You might wish to support our proposed sister site for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Farming consists of a lot of manual work.

“Farming consists of manual work. How much manual work? A lot.”

This is the better option, and is something a native speaker would say.

> Farming consists a lot of manual work.

“Farming consists of manual work. How much does it consist of manual work? A lot.”

This is slightly awkward, but still correct. It has a slightly different meaning, however: that farming consists *mostly* of manual work (but there are other kinds of work too).

Answer (score 0):

"A lot" is commonly used in informal speech with the meaning "often".

> I eat at that restaurant a lot.
>
> I think about food a lot.
>
> I think of you a lot.
>
> I beat eggs with that beater a lot.

The phrase is often placed at the end of the sentence.

Placing the phrase directly after a verb may also work.

> I think a lot about food.

For certain verbs or prepositional phrases, it may result in coupling which will confuse the sentence's meaning.

> I eat a lot at that restaurant. (emphasis on the amount of food or frequency of eating is unclear)
>
> I think a lot of you. (emphasis on my high opinion of you or the frequency of thinking is unclear)

In other cases, it may result in a sentence for which the meaning would not be instantly decipherable by native English speakers.

> I beat a lot eggs with that beater. (does not instantly convey the same meaning as "I beat eggs with that beater a lot.")

Regarding the OP's question:

- If the intended emphasis is on the amount of manual labor, the second sentence should be used.
- If the intended emphasis is on the frequency of which farming consists of manual labor, and sentence clarity is not a priority, the first sentence should be used.
- If the intended emphasis is on the frequency of which farming consists of manual labor, and sentence clarity is a priority, a new sentence should be considered.